# Getting the count of rows with the same

Tags: sql, innodb

Trying to learn some sql lately and have come across this problem.
I have a page that displays a country name and its capital in divs, requested from my db. However I want to add a feature where the user can order the display based on the number of cities that a given country contains with a population greater than 1 million. I can't figure out the query that would be needed here however.

How would I obtain as an integer value the **number** of Cities within the same country with a population greater than 100? My table format is as such. So for example, England should return 2 as there are two english cities that fulfill the criteria, USA 3, India 1 etc. etc. So USA would appear top of my newly ordered results page, followed by England then India.

I've tried union queries but I cant get hold of the value of the first query.

How can I do this?

Table A

```
*-----------------*------------*
| COUNTRY NAME    | CAPITAL    |
|     England     | London     |
|     India       | New Delhi  |
|      US         | DC         |
|                 |            |
*-----------------*------------*
```

Table B

```
 *-----------------*------------------------------*
| COUNTRY NAME    |Cities with a population > 1m  |
|     England     | London                        |
|      England    |  Birmingham                   | 
|     India       | New Delhi                     |
|      US         | DC                            |
|       US        | New York                      |
|       US        |  LA                           |
*-----------------*-------------------------------*
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that all values in table B are cities over the population required.
If not add a where clause to restrict the results..

```
SELECT [COUNTRY NAME], COUNT([COUNTRY NAME]) 
FROM Table B
GROUP BY [COUNTRY NAME]
```

Comment: that did it, thanks, slowly learning and picking up the syntax. thanks

Comment: No problem. Everyone needs help at the beginning.

Comment: Then have no spaces? I did that cause I didn't know if that was his exact column name.

Answer (score 0):

For an Oracle database it would be:

```
select a.c_name, a.c_quan
from (select country_name c_name, count(country_name) c_quan
      from table_b
      group by country_name) a
order by a.c_quan;
```

Comment: In InnoDB, you can do it without the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country,
       COUNT(*) AS NumCities
    FROM countries
    WHERE population > 100
    GROUP BY country;
```

Sample output:

```
+---------+-----------+
| country | NumCities |
+---------+-----------+
| ad      |         7 |
| ae      |         3 |
| af      |        48 |
| ag      |         8 |
| ai      |         1 |
| al      |        66 |
| am      |       287 |
| an      |        13 |
| ao      |        32 |
| ar      |        84 |
| at      |       221 |
...
| us      |      4175 |
```

A variation, this time checking for 1 million:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) AS NumCities
    FROM cities WHERE population > 1e6
    GROUP BY country
    ORDER BY NumCities DESC
    LIMIT 11;
+---------+-----------+
| country | NumCities |
+---------+-----------+
| cn      |        41 |
| in      |        33 |
| br      |        14 |
| ru      |        12 |
| jp      |        11 |
| id      |        10 |
| mx      |         9 |
| us      |         9 |
| pk      |         8 |
| ir      |         7 |
| ng      |         7 |
+---------+-----------+
11 rows in set (0.83 sec)
```

Another variant:

```
SELECT country, city, FORMAT(population,  0)
    FROM cities
    WHERE population > 1000000
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 11;
+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| country | city           | FORMAT(population,  0) |
+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| in      | Vadodara       | 1,409,565              |
| in      | Indore         | 1,837,230              |
| am      | Yerevan        | 1,093,499              |
| br      | Recife         | 1,478,118              |
| mm      | Mandalay       | 1,208,227              |
| lb      | Bayrut         | 1,252,010              |
| ht      | Port-au-Prince | 1,234,750              |
| ph      | Manila         | 10,443,877             |
| sa      | Riyadh         | 3,469,290              |
| pk      | Faisalabad     | 2,507,302              |
| cn      | Lanzhou        | 1,417,742              |
+---------+----------------+------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.98 sec)
```